# css jquery menu - toggleSlide show hide div

Tags: jquery, html, css, ipad

Check out code [here](http://jsfiddle.net/XcJwW/14/)!

These are my problems:

1. Div won't toggle to hide when self is clicked, only when i click another. ( edit: or basically anywhere )
2. All divs that are supposed to be hidden blink in when page is loaded and then disappear. Any way to avoid that? ( solved it! css display:none;)
3. The clicked div should keep its highlighted background color until another or self is clicked. Can't figure that one out.
4. (on the side) when i open the page on the ipad, the menu_row keeps its :hover backgroundcolor when clicked. That is ok, but when self is clicked and the showed div retracts it should revert to gray. Possible?

Comment: Regarding answer one, your click event handler for menuItem first hides all menuImages then unhides the clicked element's menuImage; you'll want to put logical checks into your code to see if the clicked menuItem is already open.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**1.**

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {

    //cache the `.menuImage` elements since they will be used frequently
    var $menuImages = $(".menuImage").hide('slow');
    $(".menuItem").click(function() {

        //get the `.menuImage` element that is a child of the clicked element
        var $ele = $(this).children(".menuImage");

        //`.slideUp()` all the `.menuImage` elements that aren't a child of the clicked element
        $menuImages.not($ele).slideUp(500);

        //toggle the visibility of the child of the clicked element
        $ele.slideToggle(500);
    });
});​
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/jasper/XcJwW/17/

**3.**

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    var $menuImages = $(".menuImage").hide('slow');
    $(".menuItem").click(function() {
        var $ele = $(this).children(".menuImage");

        //not only slide the rest of the `.menuImage` elements away, but also remove the `hover` class from them
        $menuImages.not($ele).slideUp(500).parent().removeClass('hover');

        //not only toggle the view of the clicked `.menuImage` element, but also toggle the `hover` class for the element
        $ele.slideToggle(500).parent().toggleClass('hover');
    });
});​
```

This requires a small tweak to your CSS:

```
#menu_row1 .menuItem:hover, #menu_row1 .menuItem.hover { background:#ff0000; }
#menu_row2 .menuItem:hover, #menu_row2 .menuItem.hover { background:#ffe100; }
#menu_row3 .menuItem:hover, #menu_row3 .menuItem.hover { background:#0033cc; }
```

Notice the user can either `hover` over one of these elements or you can give the element the `hover` class, both will have the same outcome.

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/jasper/XcJwW/20/

Comment: Thank you so very much!!! Thank you for commenting in the script so that I can understand and learn! :)

Answer (score 1):

1. That is because you hide it before you `slidetoggle` which makes it toggle to show. To fix this, hide all elements but the one directly below your current node (I'd recommend using `filter()` or `not()`). Something like:

   ```
   var self = $(this);
   // Filter out elements that are descendants of this
   $('menuItem').filter(function () { return ! self.has(this); }).hide();
   ```
2. This is because you do the `.hide('slow')` on `.ready`. Get rid of the slow and that should fix the problem.
3. Where you declare the style for `:hover`, you'll need to also declare that for a class that you add/remove on click. That way you will keep those styles.
4. Honestly, I don't know. iPad doesn't have a hover so my guess is that they are applying it based on `:active`. If you explicitly set a `:active` styling, it may use that instead of the `:hover` styling.

Comment: Thank you very much for your input. I'm on a very basic jQuery skill level and have never used filter() or not(). I'll read up on both and figure a way to do it.

Regarding #3, can I use the same class to trigger two jQuery functions, or should I use another class? 

Again, thanks for the input! :)

Comment: @Studiostefan Added an example for you. May not be the most efficient but it should work. And I'm not sure I know what you mean by "tirgger two jQuery functions".

Comment: Super. I'm fiddeling it now to try and understand. :) Thank you! What I ment by two functions is that i'm using the class of the div as trigger for toggle. Can i use the same id to change background color? It's solved really, so this is more of a general question. :)

Comment: @Studiostefan Not really. You'll want to use a class specifically for when it is selected or hovered, like shown in the accepted answer. `.hover` will be added to the element, which will "lock" the style to what you want it to be. If you try to just use the one class, you still won't know whether or not it is selected at that moment

Comment: ok!  i've tried different things and think i got it working. Thank you so very much for your time and effort!

Answer (score 1):

Change your script to this:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    $(".menuImage").hide();
    $(".menuItem").click(function() {
    $(".menuItem").not(this).children(".menuImage").hide('slow');
    $(this).children(".menuImage").slideToggle(500);
    });
});
```

The second part of your script is not needed.